# How to define the callback for an esp32 arduino ble scan result

Tags: arduino, esp32

The definition to start a BLE scan is:

```
bool start(uint32_t duration, void (*scanCompleteCB)(BLEScanResults), bool is_continue = false);
```

The second parameter seems to be the callback when a scan is complete, being somewhat new to this Im unsure how to define it.

fwiw Ive tried this:

```
void OnScanResults(BLEScanResults scanResults)
{ }
```

and used it like this:

```
scanResults = scan->start(60, OnScanResults, true);
```

but obvious to others, that didnt work.

Please help me decypher that signature

```
void (*scanCompleteCB)(BLEScanResults)
```

Comment: Your callback is empty - so nothing will happen. Have you tried inserting a `Serial.println("Scan complete");` in the callback?

Comment: sure hope there is a bigger problem than no code inside the definition

Comment: @ Tarick Welling Fear not. empty due to brevity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add & to `OnScanResults` because:

```
void (*scanCompleteCB)(BLEScanResults)
```

is a pointer to a function which takes a `BLEScanResults`, returns nothing and is called `scanCompleteCB`

So your call should be:

```
scanResults = scan->start(60, &OnScanResults, true);
```

just as a pointer to a `int` points to the address of a `int`

```
int pointedTo;
int* ptr = &pointedTo;
```

Comment: The `&` is not required for a function pointer. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer -> 'Pointers to functions'.

Comment: the tags say C so if it is indeed not C++ then that's the problem

Comment: well someone came by and added the C tag , what do i know... Ok thanks you guys solved this non mystery.  also i forgot to change the implementations return type to bool (the non call back variant gets something type 'scanResults') so that was also why it was not compiling. my bad